# How to return in a one dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a class lab, and have bwcomw stuck on one method that we have to write:

> `Member[] getMembersByYear(int firstYear, int last year)` – locates
>   and returns all members who joined between the two specified years, inclusive. This
>   method returns the members in a Java one-dimensional array. There must be no empty
>   slots in the array.

I am a little stumped on how I would go about this, I would appreciate any advice. Here is what I have wrote so far:

```
public class Club
{
// Define any necessary fields here ...
private ArrayList <Member> members;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Club
 */
public Club()
{
    // Initialise any fields here ...
    members = new ArrayList <Member>();
}

/**
 * Add a new member to the club's list of members.
 * @param member The member object to be added.
 */
public void join(Member member)
{
    members.add(member);
}

/**
 * @return The number of members (Member objects) in
 *         the club.
 */
public int numberOfMembers()
{
    if(members.size() > 0){
        return members.size(); 
    }
    else{
    return 0;
}
}

public void showMembers(){
    for(Member display: members){
        System.out.println(display.toString());

    }
}

public void showMembersByYear(int year){
    for(Member byYear: members){
         if(byYear.getYear() > 0){
             showMembers();
            }

    }
}

public Member[] getMembersByYear(int firstYear, int lastYear)
{
    Member checker = new Member();                                        //does not work, no constructor member() exists
    while((firstYear <= checker.getYear()) && (lastYear >= checker.getYear())){

    }


}

public void removeMembersByYear(int year){
    Iterator it = members.iterator();



}
}
```

Comment: Where is the Member class defined?
Code please?

Comment: @Joshua Baker,could you please clarify how would the 'member class' look like and 'removeMembersByYear(int year)' method look like?.Appreciate if you can update it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It's good to see you've had a go! Firstly, in your method you can create an `ArrayList`. Then it's case of looping through your `members` array, and when a year falls between the given range, you should add it to that new `ArrayList`. Then, simply return `ArrayList.toArray` method. Something like:

```
 public Member[] getMembersInYear(int firstYear, int secondYear)
 {
     ArrayList<Member> membersInRange = new ArrayList<Member>();
     for(every member in members) {
         if(is in year) {
             membersInRange.add(currentMember);
         }
     }
     return membersInRange.toArray();
 }
```

This will return an array with no nulls, which contains only the members that have a year that falls between `firstYear` and `secondYear`.

Comment: He has a compiler error..  `//does not work, no constructor member() exists`

Comment: membersInRange.add(what should I put in here?);

Comment: The compiler error came about because his approach was a little weird. I thought I would help out there..

Comment: @JoshuaBaker You're cycling through every member in `members`. So the current member you're testing would make sense, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Member[] getMembersByYear(int firstYear, int lastYear) {
    Iterator membersIterator = members.iterator(); 
    ArrayList<Member> returnValues = new ArrayList<Member>();
    while (membersIterator.hasNext()) {
        Member current = (Member)membersIterator.next();
        if ((current.getYear()>=firstYear) && (current.getYear()<=lastYear)) {
            returnValues.add(current);
        }
    }
    Member[] toReturn = new Member[returnValues.size()];
    returnValues.toArray(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He has a compiler error..  `//does not work, no constructor member() exists`

Comment: @GnomezGrave He already has an ArrayList called `members`, he wants to return all members who subscribed within `firstYear` and `lastYear`, he just has to iterate through `members` and compare their subscription year with the two delimiters given. He doesn't have to create new members, as they are added to `members` via `join(Member member)` so the compiler error will just disappear, as he will not use the `Member`'s constructor.

Comment: Ahhh.. yup.. Got it. Thakx for the explanation. (y)

Comment: @GnomezGrave,could you please clarify how would the 'member class' look like and 'removeMembersByYear(int year)' method look like?.Appreciate if you can update it here